# Use filter function for array with dates

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm learning to program in SWIFT and I'm doing my first app as a project. I'm making a graph with an array of struct as data, but I want to filter it and graph only what the user needs to see. I'm using the `.filter` function and it is working fine to filter elements that contain a given Integer as variable. But in the date part I can't make it work, I want that the user can be able to select a range of dates; this is the code I actually have:

```
    struct MyData {
        var gluc = Int()
        var fec = Date()
        var alimento = Int()
        var comentarios = String()
    }
    var dataArrayOrdered = [MyData]()

    func didUpdateGraph(alimentos: NSInteger, fecI: Date?, fecF: Date?, gluc: Bool, insul: Bool) {

        var newDataArray = dataArrayOrdered
        if alimentos == 6 {
            newDataArray = dataArrayOrdered
        } else {
            newDataArray = dataArrayOrdered.filter{$0.alimento == alimentos}
        }
        if fecI != nil && fecF != nil {
            newDataArray = newDataArray.filter{$0.fec >= fecI! && $0.fec <= fecF!}

        } else {
            if fecI != nil && fecF == nil {
                newDataArray = newDataArray.filter{$0.fec >= fecI!}

            } else {
                if fecI == nil && fecF != nil {
                    newDataArray = newDataArray.filter{$0.fec <= fecF!}
                }
            }
        }
        setChartData(data: newDataArray)
}
```

The function is called when the user closes a PopUpViewController with a protocol:

```
protocol ParentViewControllerDelegate2 {
    func didUpdateGraph(alimentos: NSInteger, fecI: Date?, fecF: Date?, gluc: Bool, insul: Bool)
}
```

The code inside the PopUpViewController before closing it is:

```
 @IBAction func editG(_ sender: Any) {
          var gluc: true
          var ins: true
          var fechaInicio: Date?
          var fechaFin: Date?
          var alimento = 6

        if (alimentosText) != nil {
            if alimentosText.text == "En Ayunas" {
                alimento = 0
            } else {
                if alimentosText.text == "Despues de desayunar" {
                    alimento = 1
                } else {
                    if alimentosText.text == "Antes de comer" {
                        alimento = 2
                    } else {
                        if alimentosText.text == "Despues de comer" {
                            alimento = 3
                        } else {
                            if alimentosText.text == "Antes de cenar" {
                                alimento = 4
                            } else {
                                if alimentosText.text == "Despues de cenar" {
                                    alimento = 5
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if let fI = datePickerTxt {
         fechaInicio = datePicker.date
        }
        if let fF = datePickerTxt2 {
         fechaFin = datePicker2.date
        }


    delegate?.didUpdateGraph(alimentos: alimento, fecI: fechaInicio, fecF: fechaFin, gluc: true, insul: true)
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

So looking for elements that contain a certain value in `alimentos` is working fine, but in the dates part is not making any difference; I added a print statement in every condition and it doesn't even enter into any of the date conditions, which makes me think that the `!= nil` condition is not suitable for dates, but I haven't been able to find any other option to see if there's any info stored in that variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with an Optional wrapping a Date.  But show how `didUpdateGraph` is actually called. Maybe the dates really _are_ nil. How do we know? Show actual data, actual code. Enough to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added a print statement for the dates right before the self.view.removeFromSuperview() and another inside the function, before the first if statement, and there is value for the date, so they are not nil

Comment: You have not proved that. In fact, your code shows just the opposite. In your code, `fechaInicio` and `fechaFin` _are_ nil, so you are calling `didUpdateGraph` with `fecI` and `fecF` both nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a bunch of `if - else` blocks and `nil` checks I recommend to do all necessary checks and comparisons in a **single** `filter` closure:

```
 newDataArray = newDataArray.filter { (data) -> Bool in
     let lower = fecI != nil ? data.fec >= fecI! : true
     let upper = fecF != nil ? data.fec <= fecF! : true
     return lower && upper
 }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I try to add this code and I get an error that says:  Binary operator "<=" cannot be applied to operands of type ViewController.MyData and Date, how can I make it work with the struct MyData?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I tested the closure with a simple `Date` array. I updated the answer.